# How to filter a dataframe using multiple inputs from an user

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to filter this dataframe based on some inputs from a user. This is my original dataframe -
[image]

I have created a function that takes 3 arguments and creates a subset of this dataframe.
This is the function I created -

```
def subset(posting_type, level, job_category):
  df_subset = df_filtered[(df_filtered['posting_type'] == 'posting_type') & (df_filtered['level'] == 'level') & (df_filtered['job_category'] == 'job_category')]
  return df_subset
```

I am calling this function and passing 3 parameters and am expecting to get the values which meet this filter.

```
subset('Internal', '01' ,'Administration & Human Resources')
```

But I am not getting any result. I am getting only this output. How can I get the desired value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for equality to a string literal not to the variable e.g. `'posting_type'` versus `posting_type`

```
def subset(posting_type, level, job_category):
  df_subset = df_filtered[(df_filtered['posting_type'] == posting_type) & (df_filtered['level'] == level) & (df_filtered['job_category'] == job_category)]
  return df_subset
```